# How reload element without refreshing the page using Selenium and node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, async-await

```
    let elements = await driver.findElements(By.css('div'));

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

    for(let e of elements) {
      console.log(await e.getText());

     }
```

How reload element  without refreshing the page using Selenium and nodejs? necessary to see the new elements come with ajax?